# The "android" command is deprecated. How to update sdk using terminal

Tags: android, amazon-ec2, android-emulator, android-espresso, android-sdk-manager

Im using ec2 instance which is Centos 7. Meaning I'm only using terminal not android studio. So I am trying to update my sdk using the command

`echo yes | ./android update sdk --all --filter build-tools-26.0.1 --no-ui --force`

But it says that:

```
 *************************************************************************
 The "android" command is deprecated.
 For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
 For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager
 *************************************************************************
```

How do i convert the code above using the `sdkmanager` command? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`sdkmanager --update` seems to work for me.

<a href>[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager)</a>